# Getting error while creating the AWS EC2 Own AMI using EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, centos, amazon-ami

I am creating a own centOS 64 bit ami in AWS EC2 by following this link http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_10.shtml. Now, i am in middle of creating the own AMI for EC2 instance.

So, When i issue this command **# yum -c /opt/ec2/yum/yum-xen.conf --installroot=/mnt/ec2-image -y groupinstall Base** I am getting the following error,

yum -c /opt/ec2/yum/yum-xen.conf --installroot=/mnt                                                                                        /ec2-image -y groupinstall Base
There is no installed groups file.
Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/main                                                                                        /mirror.list error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain"

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

  Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/$releasever
```

I couldn't figure out about this issue. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue and also thoughts would be helpful.

TIA...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be following reasons for the above.
1. Check if there is proxy between your server and the switch which connects you to the internet? If there is, remove the proxy.

2. Suggest using yum clear all command to clear everything.
3. Check yum.conf file and see if the repositories are commented etc. Un-comment the repositories.
4. You may also like to disable the fastest mirror plugin. Check this if 1,2,3, above fails.
5. There may simply be a problem with your dns if all above 4 options above have not worked.